# How to photograph rain drops / water drops?

Tags: canon, shooting-technique, rain

Hi, I am using a Canon EOS400D , I would like to know the best settings to use for taking photos of water drops/raindrops, I have read so many articles,but I am still really confused.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1256/6789

Comment: Do you mean rain falling or drops of water splashing?

Comment: what are you confused about?

Comment: Hi basicly water splashing .sry iam very knew to all this

Comment: Hi Akram, confused because  the articles i have read all say different things.. so i dont know if i should be using high iso and hi number f/stop

Comment: That's because it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Can you explain your goal a little further?

Comment: Helen, does this blog post help you? http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/getting-started-with-water-drop-photography/

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a trade-off. Because raindrops are small I'd say it's optimal to

- keep the focal length as long as possible to magnify the raindrops.
- focus manually on the closest raindrops available (if you're outside *in* the rain, that means focus to the near limit of your lens).
- balance between fast shutter speed (to freeze the drops) and narrow aperture (getting as much rain in focus as you can). This will require a fair bit of light or higher ISO settings.

If you have a light source illuminating the raindrops while they're in front of a darker background, they will surely be more visible. An external flash from a different angle than you lens, only hitting the raindrops and not your background, could work.

Answer (score 2):

Settings mostly depend upon the environment.  For example [image: this image] was taken at ISO 100, F2.8 @ 1/400second.  That was just a shot out of my window, after it had stopped raining and the sky was returning to a blue-colour.

If you want to use a strobe to highlight falling water, or falling rain, you'll want a similar shutter speed but you might find the aperture has to be smaller to avoid over-exposure.

Comment: ty so much for your help